# USB drive is not visible

Tags: usb, hardware, pi-4, hard-drive, mount

I mounted an Ext3 USB drive using `fstab`. It works, but I have one issue. Sometimes when I turn on the system, the drive is not visible. I can not find it in `mnt`, `media` or in the desktop.

It does not appear, even if I call `sudo fdisk -l`. But if I unplug it, I get this alert:

```
Drive was removed without ejecting
```

If I uncomment the record from `fstab` and reboot, it's still not visible. The `mount` command does nothing. There is no `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda2`

I turned it off, unplugged the drive, and tested it with my PC, and it worked. Then I plugged it back to the PI, and it was still not visible.

I tried the disk on a different USB3 port, but still nothing.

Then I plugged in an other USB drive, and then replaced it with my original drive, and finally it was visible again.

What could go wrong?

---

*Note: Please do not close it as a duplicate. I've found the other similar questions, but those answers did not work, as I explained it in my question. My problem is different.*

Comment: How would we know which questions you found and what you have tried so far? Telling us what you tried could avoid not-working suggestions... Did you e.g. check for (error) messages in the logs? Have you checked the most common problem: power issues?

Comment: Can you also add the fstab line and output of lsusb?

Comment: The `Drive was removed without ejecting` suggests it was mounted (other place than `/mnt` or `/media` perhaps? Can you find the drive with `mount` or `df`?

Comment: ... or with `lsblk`?

Answer (score 2):

You're less likely to get a good answer without providing relevant information in your question. As it's written now - your question is only [gibberish](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Jibberish).

There are a variety of tools available for reporting the status of drives and filesystems - drives that are mounted, and drives that are *connected-but-unmounted*. There is also your `/etc/fstab` - which you say "works", but then say it doesn't?

Here's what you should do if you want any help, or an answer:

1. edit your question to add the output of `cat /etc/fstab`
2. read `man lsblk`, then edit your question to add the output from this:

   ```
   $ lsblk --fs
   ```
3. Read [How to List Mounted Drives on Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-command/list-mounted-drives-on-linux/) - or something equivalent. As a minimum, edit your question to add the output from this:

   ```
   $ findmnt -t ext3
   ```